# Create SQL Statement that Returns Rows

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to search my database for a value. so I wrote:

```
command.CommandText =string.Format("SELECT * From Table1 where column1={0}",i);
int I = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It didnt work so I tried writing only `SELECT * From Table1`
and I saw that it returned -1 rows affected  (command.ExecuteNonQuery() function)
But the table isnt empty. Anyone can help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want results you need to use `ExecuteReader()`

`var reader = command.ExecuteReader();`